# Adding new unique number to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of few random numbers ( I do not know which ones it's going to be and how many of them, but it's mainly in range from 1 to 15, should not be more )

How to add new random number to this which should be as close as possible to this range and which will be unique ( can not be the same as one of the existing numbers )?

It's in javascript, example array:

```
var myarray = [4,5,1,9,6];
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? What didn't work, how did you attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: You're going to have to define "as close as possible." To check if an item is in an array, just do `if ( myarray.indexOf( someNum ) !== -1  ) { //do something }`

Comment: @elclanrs i got stuck in 2 loops I want to see if there is better solution

Comment: Simply put all your numbers in row and using an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm technique you'll get all 15 pretty shuffled

Comment: So instead of putting numbers one by one and hitting hard on algorithms, loops and stuff... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array, and you just pick your desired 'random' number out of the shuffled Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like this should work:

```
function addRandom(array, max)
{
    if(array.length === max) {
        return array;
    }

    var number = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - 1)) + 1;
    if(array.indexOf(number) === -1) {
        array.push(number);
        return array;
    }

    return addRandom(array, max);
}
```

This takes your starting array and a maximum random integer.  If the length of the array is already equal to the max integer, then the array is full and you won't ever find a new one.  Otherwise, we make a new random number between 1 and the maximum.

To do this, we use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) (which returns a float from 0-1), multiply it by one less the maximum, round the result with [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), and add 1.  If you say our max is 15, then this takes a float from 0 to 1 and multiplies it by 14 so you get 0 to 14.  This is then rounded to an integer and we add 1 so we have a range of 1 to 15.

Finally, we use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (IE 9+) to see if the number already exists.  If it doesn't, then we use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append the number and then return the new array.  Otherwise, we will run the function again and generate a new number.

Use my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQJN6/) to test this.  I start with an array with length 5, and loop through it 15 times.  You will see in the console that a random number is appended each time until every number is generated.  An example out put is:

```
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14, 7]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14, 7, 11]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14, 7, 11, 10]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14, 7, 11, 10, 13]
[4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 15, 2, 3, 12, 14, 7, 11, 10, 13]
[...]
```